# How to add parameter to custom form submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm new to sitecore development so am possibly missing some basic concepts, but using sitecore 9.11 I've managed to create a custom form submit action, that sends an email with the form values so a specific email address.
However, I want to make this action reusable for different forms with a configurable target email address. I have worked out I need to add a parameter to be set when adding the action to a submit button but have not been able to find any documentation on how to actually do that.
Can someone point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Submit Action Sitecore 9 Forms](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11424/custom-submit-action-sitecore-9-forms)

Comment: I don't think, so. I'm hoping for a parameter that is configured when attaching it action to the button, like if you use the redirect action you configure the target url.
In that answer the section about specifying the parameter is only when registering the action in Sitecore, so would need to register an instance of the action for each form.

Comment: I've have had some success with this guide https://sitecorethinker.wordpress.com/2021/11/28/speak-editor-control-to-manage-custom-submit-parameters-field-value-sitecore-form/
I now have a dialog with an email address text box. I am having other issues with the OK button being disabled, but the dialog is now linked to the parameters and submit action, so I'll class this as resolved.